# Cannot build flutter applications on other locations than disc C

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Flutter app successfully runs on local disc C but if I create the app on any other location and run the app the following error shows.
The app successfully runs only if I create the app on Local Disc C. I created the app on disk D and tried to run the app on an emulator but the build failed and the following error showed.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Educational\practicals\Flutter\socio_app\build\app\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 44s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Educational\practicals\Flutter\socio_app\build\app\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 7s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: My guess is that there is some issue with (read/write) permissions because of this text `(Access is denied)`.  Also you said that you created your project on disk D, but from the log I see that it's created on disk F: `F:\Educational...`. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I have 3 disks. I created on all of them but only runs if I create on disc C. I tried all of them